# set State when fetch response in useEffect is a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is fetching from Pokemon API which response with an array that I want to pass useState variable initialized as empty array with setValue function.

React component is below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Pokemones() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // Call fetch
      const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/");
      // Pull out the data
      const json = await res.json();
      // Save the data to array
      console.log(json.results);
 }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
        <li>
          <p>Name = {pokemon.name}</p>
          <p>URL = {pokemon.name}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I tried directly set `setPokemons(json.results);` or by `json.results.map`, received same error.
I did other tries but I got similar errors

```
      // atfet console.log and before fetchData function 

      let pok = [];
      json.results.map((p) => (pok = [...pok, p]));
      console.log(pok);
      setPokemons(pok);
    }
```

The error received on consola is:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys 
{name, url}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I guess that array is not passing to variable `pokemons` but I am able to see in console the array.  what part is that I am missing.
thanks

Comment: I added a second code demo that shows a more real-world scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    export default function Pokemones() {
      const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          // Call fetch
          const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/");
          // Pull out the data
          const json = await res.json();
          // Save the data to array
          console.log(json.results);
          setPokemons(json.results);
     }
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <ul>
          {pokemons.map((pokemon, index) => {
           return <li key={index}>
              <p>Name = {pokemon.name}</p>
              <p>URL = {pokemon.name}</p>
            </li>
          })}
        </ul>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Nice example demonstrating use of async..await. don't forget you must always handle errors, ie change `fetchData()` to `fetchData().catch(console.error)` or set an error message to display in the app. See my post to see how it's possible to make React snippets runnable in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**minimum example**

Here's a minimum working example you can run here and verify the results in your own browser.

```js
function App() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([])
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setPokemon(res.results))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [])
  
  return <ul>
    {pokemon.map(p =>
      <li key={p.name}>
        <a href={p.url}>{p.name}</a>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**going further**

We can expand the app's functionality a bit by making the list item's clickable and show the selected Pokémon details -

| *pokedex app screenshot* |
| --- |
| [image: pokedex preview] |

To do this we break the program down into three parts. First, the `List` component -

```js
function List({ pokemon, onClick }) {
  return <ul id="list">
    {pokemon.map(p =>
      <li key={p.name} onClick={onClick(p)}>
        {p.name}
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
}
```

Second, the `Details` component -

```js
function Details({ url }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    url && fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setData(res))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [url])
  
  return data
    ? <pre id="details">
        <h3>{data.name}</h3>
        {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    : <pre id="details"><h3>Select a Pokémon in the list</h3></pre>
}
```

And finally the `Pokedex` component which brings it all together -

```js
function Pokedex() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([])
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null)
  
  const selectPokemon = pokemon => event =>
    setSelected(pokemon.url)
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setPokemon(res.results))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [])
  
  return <div id="pokedex">
    <List pokemon={pokemon} onClick={selectPokemon} />
    <Details url={selected} />
  </div>
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a better idea of how React apps are put together. You can run the `Pokedex` demo below -

```js
function Pokedex() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([])
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null)
  
  const selectPokemon = pokemon => event =>
    setSelected(pokemon.url)
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setPokemon(res.results))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [])
  
  return <div id="pokedex">
    <List pokemon={pokemon} onClick={selectPokemon} />
    <Details url={selected} />
  </div>
}

function List({ pokemon, onClick }) {
  return <ul id="list">
    {pokemon.map(p =>
      <li key={p.name} onClick={onClick(p)}>
        {p.name}
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
}

function Details({ url }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    url && fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setData(res))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [url])
  
  return data
    ? <pre id="details">
        <h3>{data.name}</h3>
        {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    : <pre id="details"><h3>Select a Pokémon in the list</h3></pre>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pokedex/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body, ul, pre { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
li { cursor: pointer; }
#pokedex { display: flex; }
#list { margin-right: 2rem; }
#details { flex-grow: 1; background-color: #ffc; max-height: 100vh; overflow-y: scroll; padding-left: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```